# TextInputListener string into Label

Tags: android, libgdx, label

I took a look at https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Simple-text-input and what I want is to take the entered text from one of those dialogs into a Label. I got nullpointer with this way :

```
public class TextInputListener implements Input.TextInputListener {
public String name, year;
@Override
public void input(String text) {
    name = "Enter some text.."+ text ;

}

@Override
public void canceled() {
    name = "canceled by user";

}
```

}

Then I have a button that opens the dialog :

```
btnEdit.addListener(new ChangeListener() {




        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
        TextInputListener listener = new TextInputListener();
            Gdx.input.getTextInput(listener, "Enter information", "Name:");


        }


    });
```

And then I try to recieve that string into my Label:

```
    Label nameLabel = new Label(listener.name, labelstyle);
```

As I said I get nullpointer at that last line saying "Attempt to read from field 'TextInputListener.name' on a null object reference" . But I make sure to type in some text and press enter/ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two problems.

The first is that when you create a Label with an String object the Label will not automatically change when the String value change. At least I didn't got it to work. So you must call the `setText(String str)` method manually. But to do so, you need access to the Label object.

The second is, that you create the Label with `listener.name` but you are createing the listener object in the `changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor)` method so if you aren't creating the Label in that method the listener would be null.

So for the code you must set something like this:

```
public class TextInputListener implements Input.TextInputListener {
    private Label label;

    public TextInputListener(Label targetLabel) {
        label = targetLabel;
    }

    @Override
    public void input(String text) {
        label.setText("Enter some text.."+ text);
    }

    @Override
    public void canceled() {
        label.setText("canceled by user");
    }
}
```

And somewhere in your GUI creating method:

```
private TextInputListener listener; // Class field

    ...

    Label nameLabel = new Label("", labelstyle);
    listener = new TextInputListener(nameLabel);

    btnEdit.addListener(new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            Gdx.input.getTextInput(listener, "Enter information", "Name:", ""); // My Gdx version needed a third parameter
        }


    });

    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for good explaining. Though when run with your changes the label doesnt change the text when I press Ok after typing some text into the dialog. I suppose I need to update the screen somehow? Or re-enter or something? Cause the changes wont take place in front of my eyes when pressing enter. Please take a look at this and see if I did wrong somewhere?

Comment: Could you provide some of the relevant code that I can check. Maybe you or I miss something.

Comment: Oh ke thought you would use a Stage for GUI stuff. Are you using multiple Screens? And do you see the "just something.." after start up. Also is that really the code you are executing? Seems like there is something missing.

Comment: I added the label in StoScreen to a stage and draws/act it in render. Yes I use mulitple screens. Also, the "just something" I removed to just empty " "

Comment: If you have a Stage why do you render the label manually in the screen with `labelName.draw(game.batch, 1);` if you add the label to a stage. Here is a code example maybe that clear something up. [Code Example](http://pastebin.com/V34LWd2b) But I also recommend if the project is a little bit bigger to use a Skin from a JSON file [Skin](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Skin)

Answer (score 0):

You never set the name string in the TextInput listener.

```
Gdx.input.getTextInput(listener, "Enter information", "Name:");
```

I don't think that is setting the string using the input or it is calling `new Label(listener.name, labelstyle);` before you the user actually types the input in.

Try changing TextInputListener to

```
public class TextInputListener implements Input.TextInputListener {
public String name = "Enter some text..";
public String year;
@Override
public void input(String text) {
    name = "Enter some text.."+ text ;

}

@Override
public void canceled() {
    name = "canceled by user";

}
```

If that doesn't work try checking to see the user has entered the text then call `Label nameLabel = new Label(listener.name, labelstyle);`

Comment: Hm.. didn´t work either. I noticed though that the error now is "Attempt to read from field xxxx on a null object reference"